# How to search for specific text within HTML cell event and click corresponding button within same cell?

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Need some help with my first python project (also my first post on stackoverflow). Appreciate your time and help!

I am trying to automate regular booking on a website using selenium and chrome webdriver. The booking page is a timetable, with each cell corresponding to a timeslot and "Book" buttons within each cell/timeslot.

However, the XPATH for these buttons turns out to be dynamic.

E.g. `//*[@id="root"]/div[4]/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[69]/div[3]/button`

Each cell and button for the different timeslots has the same html class name and type. So would it be possible to search for the text in each cell (e.g. Class 1.10 7:30) and click the corresponding button within the same cell?

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="cell  even">
    <span class="d-block d-sm-none">Sat, 17th Jul</span>
    <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Saturday, 17th July</span></div>

  <div class="cell event " style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); top: 8rem; height: 6rem;">
    <div>Class 1.1</div>
    <div>07:30</div>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button">Book</button>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <div class="cell event " style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); top: 16rem; height: 6rem;">
    <div>Class 1.2</div>
    <div>08:30</div>
    <div class="position-relative">
      <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button">Book</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
If you want to match 2 texts in 2 elements as shown in the HTML you presented and I guess the texts are passed to the method as parameters, it will be something like this:

```
btn_xpath = ("//div[./div[contains(text(),'Class $class')] and (./div[contains(text(),'$time')])]//button[text()='Book']",(class=class, time=time))
driver.find_element_by_xpath(btn_xpath).click()
```

Here `class` and `time` are parameters passed from outside to select the desired class and time.
In case the selection can be unique by the time only it will be like this:

```
btn_xpath = ("//div[./div[contains(text(),'$time')]]//button[text()='Book']",(time=time))
driver.find_element_by_xpath(btn_xpath).click()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect. Would you know of any resources on this topic for me to read up more? It works but I don't quite understand the syntax / how.

Comment: You should learn about XPath. Especially XPath for Selenium since there are a lot of more complex XPath things that are exists but not supported by Selenium since Selenium supports only the XPath 1.0 version while exists XPath 2.0 etc. I can't point you on any specific tutorial, simply don't remember where I learnt all this. So just google about XPath locators and XPath locators for Selenium.